# Listing specific lines in listed files

Tags: files, grep, find

Find all files in `/tmp` that are ordinary files and print the lines
that end with `Programming`.

For this problem I know how to list all files in `/tmp`.
What I do not know how to do is whether to use `grep` or `find` to print lines that end with `Programming` for these `/tmp` files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use `find` to find the files, and `grep` to grep them.

```
find /tmp -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec grep 'Programming$' {} \;
```

Comment: Uhm, I think I'm too tired, what makes `grep 'Programming$' /tmp/*` wrong or unsuited?  (Supposing there're not *too many* files ("Argument list too long" etc))

Comment: Depending on your shell you may have to escape your `{}` as well

Comment: @sr_: The "ordinary files" requirement.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Ah, I see, `/tmp` is probably full of non-ordinary files.  Thanks.